# Hadoop 2.7.5 Yarn HA conflict and Bug

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have set up a Hadoop HA cluster including standby node for both namenode and resourcemanager such that in node A and node B both namenode and resourcemanager process will start and one node role as a standby node.
When I shutdown active node (A or B), the other will be the active node (tested). In case of I just start a node (A or B) the namenode process is ok, but the resourcemanager process is not responsive! I checked the logs and it was the following:

```
2018-01-27 17:01:43,371 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: namenode/192.168.1.210:8020. Already tried 68 time(s); retry policy is RetryPolicy[MultipleLinearRandomRetry[500x2000ms], TryOnceThenFail]
```

The node `A/192.168.1.210` is that not-started node. Its stock on a loop connecting to node A, while the namenode process is active on node B.
I set the following property to decrease the (500*2000) [(refrenced here)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.5/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRestart.html):

```
        <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.fs.state-store.retry-policy-spec</name>
        <value>1000,10</value>
        <!-- <value>2000,10</value> also checked -->
        </property>
```

But is has no effect on resource manager behavior!
Is this a bug or I'm wrong!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Hadoop `2.8` the property `yarn.node-labels.fs-store.retry-policy-spec` is added to control that situation. Adding the following property solved the problem:

```
    <property>
    <name>yarn.node-labels.fs-store.retry-policy-spec</name>
    <value>1000, 10</value>
    </property>
```

Now it try 10 time, sleeping 1000ms and after that it switch to another namenode